# Text overflows out of paragrapgh layout

Tags: paragraphs

I have no idea why it overflows out. What can I do? connect_metu.mobi_2.php is out of the layout.

[image: the right bottom side of the paragrapgh]

Comment: Perhaps you can add "Furthermore, the signal connect_metu.mobi_2.php opens and..." so that the break occurs after "the signal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX tries to make lines look good and line up both left and right by varying the space between words on different lines but there's only so far it's willing to stretch this space.

If you don't mind a hyphen in the filename, type `\-` for an optional hyphen (which doesn't appear if TeX didn't break a line there), like on the fourth line of your paragraph. I'd personnaly hyphenate `connect_me\-tu.mobi_2.php`.

Alternately, you can manually break the line before "The connect_metu..." by inserting a `\\` (two backslashes) there which doesn't start a new paragraph.